# How to make uWSGI main thread not serve requests for the Django web application?

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio, uwsgi

In my Django application, in the `__init__.py`, I have a class which spins up an event loop.

```
class X:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

  async def foo(self):
    ...

  def do_stuff(self):
    # some logic here
    self.__loop.run_until_complete(foo())
```

In the `__init__.py` I just have

```
x = X()
```

In my Django views, I do

```
from myapp import x

def example_view(request):
  result = x.do_stuff()
  return JsonResponse({"result": result})
```

But the problem is that with uWSGI, if the thread that serves the request is same as that was used during initialization, I get the Django's `SynchronousOnlyOperation` exception as it detects a running event loop in that particular thread.

So my question is, is there a way not to use that initializing thread for serving requests or some other alternative to fix this issue?

uwSGI is configured to run multiple processes and multiple threads, with `--enable-threads`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```py
class X:

    async def foo(self):
        ...

    def do_stuff(self):
        asyncio.run(foo())
```

Comment: Yeah, that is a possible solution I might have to go for anyway. But the thing is I am using `asyncio.BoundedSemaphore` and I don't think that will make sense if a new event loop is being created for each function call.

Comment: Had to go with this solution anyway, since the `loop.run_until_complete` is not thread safe and even though there is an equivalent thread-safe method, it feels to "hacky" to work with (not to mention the problem would still persist). Marking as accepted.